# MVC Removing the need to pre-fix the Project Name in a model binding within a view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have this model:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace MVCProjectName.Models.Login
{
    public class LoginViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Remember me")]
        public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have this view:

```
@model MVCProjectName.Models.Login.LoginViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Login";
}

<h1>User Login</h1>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <form method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Email"></label>
                <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Password"></label>
                <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label asp-for="RememberMe">
                        <input asp-for="RememberMe" />
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there any way in which we can have the model binding reduced to just this:

```
@model Models.Login.LoginViewModel
```

Or this:

```
@model Login.LoginViewModel
```

Given that the `LoginViewModel` should be in the same namespace anyway, and that the `Models` folder is in the root. Can we reduce the `@model` statements above more via any means?

Comment: Try adding a `@using MVCProjectName.Models`. If that works, you can put that into `_ViewImports.cshtml` to apply globally to all views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your project's namespace as a `using` statement into the `\Views\_ViewImports.cshtml`.

[MS documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/layout?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two options:
1. Change the namespace of LoginViewModel itself
2. In your view, add @using MVCProjectName and then add @mode Models.Login.LoginViewModel

One other thing you might be able to try is if you have a layout page. You can do the using in that and then in any view that uses that layout page would just need to use the model name as I mentioned in option 2.